# Проблемы с ncurses

Tags: c++, linux, linux-mint, ncurses

Не получается скомпилировать простецкую программу на c++, используя ncurses :

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();                   
    printw("Hello world!\n");  
    refresh();                   
    getch();                   
    endwin();                    
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор(g++) выдает:

```
    /tmp/ccPsJIg5.o: In function `main':
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `initscr'
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `printw'
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `refresh'
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `stdscr'
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `wgetch'
    temp.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `endwin'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Скомпилировал вроде правильно: `g++ -Wall -ansi -std=gnu++11  -lncurses -o temp  temp.cpp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-lncurses` следует поставить в конец